# Apache Rewrite not working

Tags: mod-rewrite, redirect, apache2

I have a very strange thing happening in my apache2 setup. I just want to redirect HTTP to HTTPS. I have tried all possible ways, like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

I put this in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` but it simply didn't work.

I then put the above in `<VirtualHost *:80>` and it works, but I instead get

> This page isn’t working
>   kanzan.se redirected you too many times.

This is because I use port 80 behind a cache server (Varnish) and in front of that I use a `<VirtualHost *:443>`. Every works fine except for this.

I even had this problem before I put Varnish there, but then I could solve it by putting the rewriting in `<VirtualHost *:80>` since that worked.

Somehow Apache doesn't care about its main config file `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I put this in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` but it simply didn't work.

If by that you mean you put the directives directly in the server, in a *server* context, then the directives won't do anything if you have mod_rewrite directives in the `<VirtualHost>` being accessed. You would need to enable mod_rewrite inheritance (but you may not want to do that).

If you are behind a proxy server that manages your SSL then your application server is always serving content over port 80, so the `HTTPS` server variable is never `on` - hence your redirect loop.

However, the proxy server should set the `X-Forwarded-Proto` request header, indicating (to your application server) which protocol is being used. eg. Either `http` or `https`. So, you could probably change your directive to read the following instead:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} ^http$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

Then again, your config may be setting some other non-standard header (or environment variable) that you would need to use instead.

Comment: Yes, the part about rewrite in the server context I can confirm now.. I got it working by removing all rewrites in the main config file and added it in virtualhost for port 80. To not going in the recursive loop I passed a header value from Varnish and just checked the existence of that in the condition for the rewrite.